# Restricting the Number of Blank Lines in TinyMCE Editor

Tags: javascript, regex, tinymce

I am working with TinyMCE in JavaScript and facing a challenge in implementing a restriction on the number of blank lines users can input. The goal is to allow a maximum of two empty lines before and after any text within the TinyMCE editor, regardless of whether the user pressed *Enter* (creating `<p>` blocks) or used *Shift + Enter* (creating `<br>` elements).

I have successfully handled cases involving three or more `<br>` elements and empty `<p>` tags using regular expressions like:

```
//replace 4 and more <br> for 3 <br>
var updatedContent = content.replace(/((<br\s*\/?>\s*){4,})/gm, '<br><br><br>');

//Similar approach for 3 or more EMPTY <p> tags - replace for 2
```

3 `<br>` elements after some text creates 2 blank lines, meanwhile 3 empty `<p>` tags creates 3 lines. However, if 3 `<br>` elements are right after opening `<p>` tag it creates also 3 lines:

```
<p><br><br><br>sometext<br><br><br></p> //-> 3 empty lines before sometext but 2 after.
```

this is easy to handle as well. I am looking if there is more then 2 `<br>` elements after opening `<p>` tag and replace them with exactly 2..

Btw: tinymce puts everything inside `<p>` tags, so if I try to replace empty `<p></p>` for `<br>` it creates `<p><br><p>` which is same as `<p></p>` and tinymce automaticaly convert it to this form, so I am unable to get rid of them.

but I'm struggling with scenarios like:

```
<p>text<br><br></p>
<p><br><br></p>
<p>Before this text, there are three blank lines; the allowed maximum is two<br><br></p>
<p><br><br>Text with three blank lines before</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p><br><br>This is text with four blank lines before<br></p>
<p> "<br>" right in front of "</p>" doesn't have any effect on blank lines</p>
<p><br><br></p>
<p></p>
<p>Before this text, there are three blank lines; the allowed maximum is two<br></p>
```

I've attempted various regular expressions, but none seem to cover all cases correctly. Could someone provide insights or a solution on how to handle these scenarios and limit the number of blank lines to a maximum of two before and after any text within the TinyMCE editor? If there is any easier way to do this in tinymce just let me know.

Comment: Hey, I think the following example might give you a direction to go in. I'm not submitting it as an answer because I don't think it captures your request fully since you need capture groups. Regardless, here is my attempt to capture the situations you were talking about:

`<p><\/p>(\n<p><\/p>)+|<p><br>(<br>)+(<\/p>)?|<br>{2}(<br>(?!<\/p>))+`

with the regexr link: <regexr.com/7qblb>.

Comment: Note that `<p></p>` does not actually create a blank line as such; it is the margin around it that creates the effect of a blank line (try setting `p { margin : 0 }` to see this). Do you want to take account of that? Also, when deleting "extra" lines, do you want to prefer `<br>` or `<p></p>`?

Comment: @Nick Margin around ```<p>``` elements is necessary. So I can't set it to 0. Moreover, if I set the margin to 0, it would prevent using the enter as a blank line completely, which I can't do. I'd like to keep the margin difference between using shift+enter and enter (similar to how it is in Word - client's wish.) And for the last question, what is easier, probably ```<br> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after several attempts, hours of struggling, cursing, and desperation, I believe I have successfully captured all possible variations of occurrences of two lines. Here is the code:

```
    //replace 4 and more <br> for 3 <br>
    var updatedContent = content.replace(/((<br\s*\/?>\s*){4,})/gm, '<br><br><br>');

    //replace <p> followed by 3 or more <br> with <p> and 2 <br>
    updatedContent = updatedContent.replace(/<p>\s*(<br\s*\/?>\s*){3,}/gm, '<p><br><br>');
    
    //replace 4 or more <br> followed by </p> with 3 <br> and </p>
    updatedContent = updatedContent.replace(/(<br\s*\/?>\s*){3,}\s*<\/p>/gm, '<br><br><br></p>');
    
    //replace 2 or more consecutive occurrences of <p> (any number of <br>) </p>  with <p></p><p></p>
    updatedContent = updatedContent.replace(/(<p>\s*(<br\s*\/?>\s*)*<\/p>\s*){2,}/g, '<p></p><p></p>');
    
    //replace <br><br><br></p><p>empty or <br>s</p> with <br><br><br></p>
    updatedContent = updatedContent.replace(/<br\s*\/?>\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*<\/p>(\s*<p>\s*(<br\s*\/?>\s*)*\s*<\/p>\s*)*/gm, '<br><br><br></p>');
    
    //replace <br><br></p><p>empty or <br></p> with <br><br></p><p></p>
    updatedContent = updatedContent.replace(/<br\s*\/?>\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*<\/p>(\s*<p>\s*(<br\s*\/?>\s*)*\s*<\/p>\s*)+/gm, '<br><br></p><p></p>');
    
    //replace <br><br><br></p><p>empty or <br> with <br><br><br></p><p>
    updatedContent = updatedContent.replace(/<br\s*\/?>\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*<\/p>\s*<p>\s*(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+/gm, '<br><br><br></p><p>');

    //replace <br><br></p><p>empty or <br> with <br><br></p><p><br>
    updatedContent = updatedContent.replace(/<br\s*\/?>\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*<\/p>\s*<p>\s*(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+/gm, '<br><br></p><p><br>');
    
    //replace 2 or more consecutive occurrences of <p> (any number of <br>) </p> followed by <p> and any number of <br>  with <p></p><p></p><p>
    updatedContent = updatedContent.replace(/(<p>\s*(<br\s*\/?>\s*)*<\/p>\s*){2,}<p>\s*(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+/gm, '<p></p><p></p><p>');
            
    //replace <br><br><p></p><p> any number of <br> with <br><br></p><p></p><p>
    updatedContent = updatedContent.replace(/<br\s*\/?>\s*<br\s*\/?><\/p>\s*<p>\s*<\/p>\s*<p>\s*(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+/gm, '<br><br></p><p></p><p>');

    //replace 2 or more consecutive occurrences of <p> (any number of <br>) </p>  with <p></p><p></p>
    updatedContent = updatedContent.replace(/(<p>\s*(<br\s*\/?>\s*)*<\/p>\s*){1,}<p>\s*(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+/gm, '<p></p><p><br>');
```